# cocos2d touch with parallax

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, sprite, parallax

I have severals layers and added some sprites to them;
Trying to acces them in this way:

```
-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

    if(CGRectContainsPoint([[self getChildByTag:tagNumber] boundingBox], location)) {
        CCLOG(@"You've touched the sprite!");
    }
}
```

a strange thing is that if don't have this method:

```
-(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    return YES;
}
```

my app crashed when I touch the screen. Any idea what might be?

**UPDATE:**

```
-(void) registerWithTouchDispatcher
{
    [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self 
                                                     priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you receive the ccTouchBegan event but not ccTouchesBegan (note the plural) you're using the [CCTargetedTouchDelegate](http://learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/cocos2d-iphone/html/protocol_c_c_targeted_touch_delegate-p.html) protocol. You probably have registered your class with CCTouchDispatcher addTargetedDelegate and thus must stick to using the CCTargetedTouchDelegate protocol whose methods are the singular versions of ccTouchXXXX and not ccTouchesXXXX.

You should also heed the warnings Xcode shows you. If you don't implement ccTouchBegan I'm certain that a "may not respond to selector" warning may appear. All warnings should be taken serious (in fact so much so that I recommend to turn on "Treat all warnings as errors").

Answer (score 0):

Any errors produced in the console? Something about an unrecognized selector? It's been a while since I was involved with cocos2D, but you should check if the second method overrides the first one. If it actually does, then when it doesn't exist, your program will use the first one (the one that returns void), thus stumbling upon an actual bug in your code implementation. I would set a breakpoint inside the first line of '-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event', delete the function that returns BOOL, and then I would see step by step what would happen when using the debugger.

And please post your console log. I'm believe that you should have a "selector not found", "child not found" or "invalid argument exception due to nil argument" problem.

Just a thought.

Comment: [here's my log](http://pastie.org/private/qndnex0pgflefwhfuxlxpw) ; Tried what you've said to me and my `ccTouchesBegan` method isn't called